# getting dictionary from pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I need to write a function in pandas which gets two series as arguments: one is the grades of several students, another is their gender. As a return I need to get a dictionary with keys "male" or "female" and values which are the means of the grades over gender... As an example,if

```
grades = pd.Series([5, 4, 3, 5, 2])
```

and

```
genders = pd.Series(["female", "male", "male", "female", "male"])
```

the function must return a dictionary

```
{'male': 3.0, 'female': 5.0}
```

I know that I may create a data frame with columns which are these two series and then use groupby and to_dict() but have no idea how..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
In [96]: grades.groupby(genders).mean().to_dict()
Out[96]: {'female': 5L, 'male': 3L}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
grades.groupby(genders).mean().to_dict()
```